# Как сохранить картинку по прямой ссылке с phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Есть url картинки

`http://www.site.com/img.jpg`

Как можно сохранить такую картинку с помощью phantomjs?

Comment: Насколько я помню, фантом не позволяет получить в пользовательских скриптах сами данные, которые передаются по сети. Нужно патчить фантома, тогда возможность сохранять данные из скрипта появляется.

Comment: Это [открытая проблема на GitHub в самом PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052). Напрямую -- никак.

Comment: В каспере реализована такая функция: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download